# Firebase push() and the main thread

Tags: firebase

I am confused about the functionality of push() in Firebase, even after reading the docs. They present the following code:

```
// Generate a reference to a new location and add some data using push()
var newPostRef = postsRef.push();
// Get the unique ID generated by push()
var postID = newPostRef.key();
```

Does push() conduct a server query to get a unique ID (thus lagging the main thread--which seems not smart), or does it simply create a "dirty" unique ID that is later checked for uniqueness against the master ledger in the server? The docs seem kind of unclear about the robustness of the ID so I want to make sure.

Comment: For some reason I was under the impression that the ID is based off of the current time, which would have a very small chance of collision unless you had thousands of requests per second. So I guess that's not the whole story...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase's `push()` method is a pure client-side method. It generates a key based on the current time (corrected for the last known offset of the local clock from the server) and a lot of random information. The key it generates is statistically guaranteed to be unique.

To learn more about these keys, see this blog post: [The 2^120 Ways to Ensure Unique Identifiers](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html).

Comment: Ah, do you have an opinion on this method versus Parse's dirty field method? They both seem really functional.

Comment: Nope, I have nothing to add on comparing the two. If you're afraid of collisions: I've worked with Firebase for a long time and have never seen (nor heard reports) of a collision in push IDs. It's the same as when I first learned about UUIDs. At first it feels very uncomfortable to trust them. But after a while you realize that "statistically guaranteed" is pretty darn likely.